# mariadb insert problem "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to perform the following query to check the database daily with a batch file in Windows, but an error occurs.

```
select     'INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES ('''||reg_dt||''');'
from     (
select    *
        from     
         (select convert(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m%d:%H'),char ) "reg_dt") reg_dt
) tt;  

Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES (''
Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '');'
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES (''
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '20240320:15'
```

Is there any solution?

but The result of the select statement comes out fine. and mariadb version is 10.0.20

[image]

Comment: What type is `REG_DT`? WHy not just insert `NOW()` or [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/current_date/) if you just want today.

Comment: mariadb 10.0 has been unsupported for almost 5 years.  do upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible

Comment: how are you running this query?  what is the purpose of the `'''||reg_dt||''''`?

Comment: all the subqueries and cast are unneeded, you can just do `INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES (DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d:%H'))`  though if this is in a batch file, you may need to do `%%Y%%m%%d:%%H`

Comment: It is complaining _at least_ about the use of `:` in a numeric context.

Comment: I need to save it in sqlite db as varchar type.

Answer (score 0):

Mariadb doesn't know || as Concatenation possibility, as long as you don't have  set sql_mode="PIPES_AS_CONCAT" , which is usually not the case  , you should keep using `CONCAT`.

something else,  you made too complicated so i removed it

```
CREATE tABLE MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT  varchar(14))
```

```
select    CONCAT( "INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES ('", reg_dt_ , "');") into @sql
from
 
         (select convert(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m%d:%H'),char ) as reg_dt_) reg_dt_tab
```

```
select convert(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m%d:%H'),char ) as reg_dt
```

| reg_dt |
| --- |
| 20240321:01 |

```
SELECT @sql
```

| @sql |
| --- |
| INSERT INTO MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE (REG_DT) VALUES ('20240321:01'); |

```
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

> ```
> Statement prepared
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DB_RESOURCE_USAGE
```

| REG_DT |
| --- |
| 20240321:01 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cg7VgIlM)

Comment: MariaDB also supports concatenation via pipes if you set sql_mode="PIPES_AS_CONCAT"